# Filter items that are older than a specific date

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a portion of a script that will currently provide me items that are up to a specific day old. I would like it instead to go back that many days a d then get anything older than that date. How should I modify this to achieve that result?

```
If ($null -notlike $UpdatedSinceDays) {
$filterDate = ("(LastUpdatedDateTime gt {0})" -f (Get-Date (get-date).AddDays($UpdatedSinceDays) -UFormat %y-%m-%dT00:00:00z))
If ($null -eq $filterbuilder) {
$filterbuilder = $filterDate
}
Else {
Rest of filter statement 
}
}
```

$filterbuilder gets fed into  $ParamCollection.Filter to add several filters to a command.

Comment: Change `gt` for `lt` or `le` depending on what you want.

Comment: Get-Childtem -recurse 'C:\PS' | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt "1/1/2021"} | select LastWritetimeUTC, FullName

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon your solution was the easiest to implement and worked first try. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The **Get-ChildItem cmdlet** in PowerShell gets files from the specified directory and using recurse parameters it recursively gets files from folders and subfolders.

The **Where-Object cmdlet** is used to filter condition for files having CreationTime is older than 15 days.

**Example Script** to find all files older than 15 days in the C:\temp directory

```
# Search Path
$Folder = "C:\temp\"

# Search using gci cmdlet
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) }
```

[image: Search using gci cmdlet]